# ask question in a channel, save the answer, and depend of that answer do something, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

i would like to ask a question, so here its my code to make myself as clear as possible:

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const prompts = require('prompts');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first();
    const general = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general");


let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'user@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password123'
  }
});

let response = prompt(`please give me your mail `);

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'user@gmail.com',
        to: `${response}`,
        subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
        text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});

}      
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'mail'
}
```

so here i want to ask the Mail, and i will send a mail to him!, i followed the steps at this pague:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts

i downloaded:

### npm i prompts, npm install --save prompts

and in this part of the code is where i get the question:

```
let response = prompt(`please give me your mail `);
```

i think im using wrong that part, so i would aprreciate your help and i hope i was clear :)

Comment: If you `console.log(response)` what is the output?

Comment: Did you check Message Collectors? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html